# Indentify the boolean tag in jersey request

Tags: xml, jaxb, jersey

In Jersey PUT request I am passing a xml file as data input for cURL.

How should I test the particular boolean value in xml input file, because JAXB converts all the non-true values to false. and if the tag isnt present even then it gives the value as false.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the attribute using the object type Boolean instead of the primitive boolean.

Comment: I am not able to change that now. Is there a way to deal with primitive types?